# How to create a 100% Read-Only profile in Salesforce (including 'Salesforce objects' as shown in DataLoader)?

Tags: data-loader, permissions, profile, custom-profile, read-only

Please hear me out completely. I am trying to create a profile where user can read data (= export) from Data Loader, but NOT insert/edit/delete ANYTHING back through it. So I created a profile with Salesforce license type, gave access to Data Loader, set all Object Settings to 'Read' and stripped several System Permissions (for Events, Tasks etc).

The problem? When I login via Data Loader as that profile user, attempt to 'Insert' and check the box 'Show all Salesforce objects', I get a ton of system objects like 'Share', 'Tag', in addition to User, Attachment, CaseComment, Email Template, Folder, Vote, etc (this list is far from exhaustive).

*How can I strip insert/edit/delete access for EVERY object out there, especially 'Salesforce objects', so this profile is as naked as possible when viewed from DataLoader?*

Or,

*Can the Data Loader itself be restricted to show 'Export' option ONLY and remove all other options?*

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no individual object permissions you can assign to Share, History, Tag, etc objects. You won't be able to remove those objects, because security is controlled by the parent record. It won't matter in the long run, as without Edit permission, most of these settings are read-only for the user. For example, you can't tag a record if you don't have Edit permission, and you can't share a record unless you own it, are a manager of the owner, have Full Access, or are an administrator (Modify All Data).

Comment: Ok, thank you. How about the User object?

Comment: @LightningEvangelist One can always see the User object, but again, they won't be able edit users with out Manage Users or being configured as a Delegated Administrator; a user needs access to their own record for things like changing their time zone or other preferences. Depending on how your User Sharing is set up, you can choose if they can see other users or not.